# User dependend resource filter in Python-eve RestApi Framework

Tags: python, api, rest, authentication, eve

I want to implement a "more complex" filter based on the access rights of the user in Python eve restframework.

### Problem

We have token authentification, the user account is fetched in the `TokenAuth` Class.
The user has some contracts, each contract has bills. I want to implement an endpoint /bills which shows bills of his contract. We use `mongodb`.

For better understanding, someting like the SQL Statement `"SELECT * FROM bills WHERE bills.contract IN user.contracts"`

```
user { contracts : ["a","b","c"] }
bills { contract: "a" }
```

### Background information

```
class TokenAuth(TokenAuthBase):
    def check_auth(self, token, allowed_roles, resource, method):
       users = app.data.driver.db['users']
       TokenAuth.account = users.find_one(lookup)
       ...
```

(update)

### User-Restricted Resource Access¶ (URRA)

For the situation of ***user 1 : n bill*** relation, URRA will do the job. See [URRA in python eve docs](http://python-eve.org/authentication.html#user-restricted-resource-access).

In a more complicated case it is necessary to write a custom filter query. I need this option :).

### Update

I found a solution, see updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Nicola Iaorcci I found a solution.

First, I use a custom authentication class for every endpoint.

```
class MyCreditNoteAuth(TokenAuthBase):
   def check_auth(self, token, allowed_roles, resource, method):
        account = app.data.driver.db['users'].find_one({'api_access_token': token})
```

This method fetches the user's account from mongodb and now I have access to his contract ids.

Second, still in the upper method I update the filter of the datasource on each request:

```
mynotes['datasource']['filter']['contract'] = { '$in': account['contracts'] }
```

Now the customer sees only his own "notes" on the given endpoint.

Comment: Can you gist a more complete example? I'm having a hard time replicating this. thanks!

Comment: Looking for this as well

Answer (score 2):

What about [Predefined Database Filters](http://python-eve.org/config.html#filter) then?

```
bills = {
    'datasource': {
        'source': 'bills',
        'filter': {'field1': 'value1', 'field2': 'value2'}
    }
}
```

`source` is a mongodb collection; `filter` is a mongodb query. It will be transparently applied to any request hitting the endpoint (before client queries).

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be better to do this on a per request basis.  Modifying the `'DOMAIN'` might lead to cases where multiple people are logged in and sending requests at the same time and the domain changes in between requests depending on how you implement that sort of thing.  Mayby something like this would work:

```
from eve import Eve
from eve.auth import BasicAuth

def pre_get_api_stuff(resource, request, lookup):
    username = request.authorization['username']
    accounts = app.data.driver.db['accounts']
    account = accounts.find_one({'username': username})
    if resource == 'notes':
        lookup.update({'username': username})

app = Eve(auth=BasicAuth)
app.on_pre_GET += pre_get_api_stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in to [User-Restricted Resource Access](http://python-eve.org/authentication.html#user-restricted-resource-access)?

At quick glance I'd say that by storing the user token (or id, or whatever identifies the user in your setup) with your bill documents and then enabling URRA at the `bills`endpoint, would do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the thing is, that URRA requires user 1:n bill releation, in this case it is user n:m contracts 1:n bills.  So I need to overwrite the URRA filter with a more complex one? is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

A more complete example is as follows, suppose we have the following in settings.py

```
note_schema = {
    'user_id': {
        'type': 'objectid',
        'required': True,
        'readonly': True
    }
}
user_schema = {
    'username': {
        'type': 'string',
        'required': True,
        'unique': True,
    },
    'password': {
        'type': 'string',
        'required': True,
    },
    'token': {
        'type': 'string',
        'required': True,
    }
}

DOMAIN = {
    'user': {
        'schema': user_schema,
    },
    'note': {
        'schema': note_schema,
    },
}
```

And the auth comes with adding a filter based on the username, the logic of filter is simple here, but you could add anything you want to the filter

```
class MyAuth(BasicAuth):
    def check_auth(self, token, allowed_roles, resource, method):
        username = get_username_from_token(token)
        if resource == 'note':
            note = app.config['DOMAIN']['note']
            user = app.data.driver.db['user'].find_one({'username': username})
            note['datasource']['filter'] = {'user_id': user['_id']}

        return True
```